# Call a quick action from a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-quickaction

I created a quick action and would like to fire it from a lightning component, e.g. from a click event of a button. This [article](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2017/11/forcecreaterecord-example-in-salesforce.html) creates the quick action dynamically, but I would like to reference an existing quick action I pre-defined in the setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can call a quick action but only if you are on the record page and that page has the quick action you are trying to call.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:quickActionAPI/documentation

I spent forever trying to use this to find it a fail... What you can do is use your javascript controller to go to the component you built by using navigate to component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToComponent/documentation

You might have to create an overlay (modal) to use your component if you want the component to work like a modal/quick action. I did this. I felt it was way more work than it should be but the users do not know the difference.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation